# Can I take a computer off of Ubuntu Livepatch?

Tags: license, canonical-livepatch

Canonical offers [livepatching](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch) for its kernel, where every home user can get three licenses.

However, I'd like to know how I can de-register a machine from my license. If I get rid of a computer, I'd rather not lose one of my three licenses.

Is there a formalized procedure to deactivate a machine's license and transfer it to a new machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just run

```
sudo snap run canonical-livepatch disable
```

Comment: And this actually frees up one of the livepatch licenses again? I've dealt with software where disabling things doesn't give you the license back, so I want to verify with Ubuntu.

Comment: I’ve done this on more than three machines(the limit) and it worked fine.

Comment: Do I have to run this on the old machine? What if it was a cloud instance and it's deleted. How do I reset all registered machines? Thanks

Comment: @Houman did you ever find the answer to your follow-up question about cloud instances?

Comment: @DGinzberg I'm no longer using Ubuntu. But I remember that only the last three activated devices were kept. Hence older devices simply fall off the cliff and get removed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively go to *Software and Updates >> Livepatch* and turn the slider to off.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to do the following:

- Check out `man ua` to see what the Ubuntu Advanced services are;
- `ua status` to see how your settings are configured;
- `sudo ua disable livepatch` and then `ua status` for control.