# Is there a way to disable livepatch witch I have already uninstalled ubuntu?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I have used livepatch while using ubuntu, and uninstalled ubuntu and installed other OS.
Can I disable livepatch for that device? (Cause 3 device per user free livepatch one)

Comment: Please [edit] to change `witch` to `which`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You should have done that before removing Ubuntu.

See [How to disable livepatch tokens remotely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032700/how-to-disable-livepatch-tokens-remotely) and [Can I take a computer off of Ubuntu Livepatch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958462/can-i-take-a-computer-off-of-ubuntu-livepatch)

From that topic I would believe you can add more than 3 though (but it is likely only 3 can be active at the same time). Or that the number is not enforced ;)

You probably need to [contact service support](https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch) to be sure.