# Removing unnecessary Software Updating apps

Tags: update-manager, software-uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 yesterday and something that bothers me is that i have 4 apps that should be taking care of updating the distro. My question is which ones can be removed safely?

1. Software Updater
2. Software & Updates
3. Ubuntu Software
4. Livepatch - this is not even turned on

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking that some of those applications are bloat - they are not. If you intend to use the GUI, you should retain them all.

Comment: some answers ............................ https://askubuntu.com/a/783075/434474 https://askubuntu.com/a/979187/434474 https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399169

Comment: Even though they have similar names they all serve different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each has a different lane:

1. Software Updater is the actual application that does updating (via apt). You cannot change apt settings from within the application.
2. Software & Updates is the control panel to change Software Updater's (and other apt-related) settings.
3. Ubuntu Software is the app store. While you can use it for updating, it won't be automatic. If you do decide to use Ubuntu Software for updating, it will simply hand the job to Software Updater.
4. Livepatch is a separate kernel-only update service that is independent of apt and deb software packages. It's optional. Using it simply updates your kernel (and nothing else) without requiring a reboot.

1, 2, and 3 work together - think of them as three points of entry to apt: Updating, Settings, and Add/Remove.

Comment: awesome, appreciate the explanation!